# presentModalViewController on parent viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ios4

I have a viewcontroller, where I load subviews on. In those subviews I have a UIButton which will show a modalViewController. If I call the function on the main viewcontroller, I get the modal exactly in the middle as I want them to be, but if I call the exact same method in the view I've added as a subview the modal is presented somewhere on the right side of the screen. So now is my question: how can I present the modal on the super view instead? Or how do I put the modalview in center? Because the views I've added as subviews contains data which the modalpopup needs.

This is how I present the modal:

```
MapViewer *map = [[MapViewer alloc] init];
map.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:map animated:YES];
[map release];
```

Hope somebody can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Maybe useful to be more clear:

AppDelegate.m

-> MainWindow.m

```
-> OtherViewController.m
```

So I add an x amount of OtherViewControllers as subviews to MainWindow. The OtherViewController contains the function mentioned above. But the map needs to be displayed as a modal on the MainWindow, and not on the OtherViewController so it gets nicely centered etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've managed to get it working using the notificationcenter so I can call a method on the MainWindow from other views. So if anyone is asking the same question, have a look at the notificationcenter :D

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might do is set the target of the UIButton object to the main view controller using setTarget:action: method.